# Long Touch event with Timer and Confirmation Box for iOS deployment in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a project where I have a scrolling list. I would like for my user to be able to "long touch" an item on the list so that they can delete it.

I am developing in Air for iOS using Flash CS6 so I don't really know much about the appropriate MultiTouch gestures for iOS deployment.

In my mind, the animation steps I would like to go like so..

1. Previously invisible button called btn_delete inside the Item movieclip will appear when Long Touch starts + timer begins
2. Intermediate step: btn_delete will rotate 90 degrees using TweenMax Rotate (I have this covered)
3. Final step: when timer reaches it's conclusion, a dialog box / confirmation box will pop up and ask the user if they are sure if they want to delete the item.

So here is some generic code I've written quickly to give you an idea of my structure so far (I've omitted the interlinking listener functions):

```
function exampleFunction {
    _item.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
}

//-- Long Press Listener Functions--//
function onTouchBegin(eBegin:TouchEvent) {
    trace("start");
}

function onTouchRotate(eEnd:TouchEvent) {
    trace("rotation of image");
}

function onTouchEnd(eEnd:TouchEvent) {
    trace("end");
}
```

If anyone has a piece of code they've already written that roughly matches my criteria then please post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `MouseEvent` for this.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer( 500 ); //ms
timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler );

listItem.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler );

function mouseDownHandler( e:MouseEvent ):void {
    timer.start();
    stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler );
}

function mouseUpHandler( e:MouseEvent ):void {
    //just some clean up to reset the timer and remove the mouse up event listener from the stage 
    timer.reset();
    stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler );
}

function timerCompleteHandler( e:TimerEvent ):void {
    timer.reset();
    stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler );

    //do delete actions here
}
```

So on mouse down, you start your timer and listen for a mouse up event (on the stage and not the component. That is important. If you want to know why, try it on the component and experiment). On mouse up, you reset the timer so the next time you mouse down, it starts at 0 (reset() has the added benefit of stopping the timer). On timer complete, you do the same as in mouse up in addition to your delete code.

I'm using a MouseEvent here just because it behaves identical to TouchEvent (for the most part) in this instance and it could be used on the desktop (meaning you can test in the emulator and you could add this to other projects if you wanted)

UPDATE:
Just reread your question and realized I missed the rotate. For this, just add another timer with a separate complete handler that and in that function, ONLY do the rotation and reset that timer.

Comment: Before I go ahead testing your answer, what are the subtle differences between `MouseEvent` and `TouchEvent` that you are aware of so I am aware of the limitations when I come to deploy to my iPhone?

Comment: There aren't any in this case that I can think of. TouchEvent has more precise events for touch devices, but most of the time they are unneeded. BEGIN, TAP, and OUT are almost identical to MOUSE_DOWN, CLICK, and MOUSE_UP. There may be a difference in when they are called, but I've never tested it so I can't tell you for sure. For the most part, though, you can stick with MouseEvents.

Comment: Okay, I have implemented your code but when it comes to testing in the Air Debug Launcher for Desktop it doesn't respond to the MOUSE_DOWN event (?). I've zipped up my project on my website, if you could take a look at it, I would be eternally grateful! (http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/resources/RecipeMatcher.zip) [Silly thought: I am using a Mac, could the mac trackpad be the problem?)

Comment: You're only applying the MOUSE_DOWN to a single item, the last one created.

Comment: Okay so if I wanted to apply the MOUSE_DOWN to all instances on the stage, but also want it to target only the one that is clicked, what would be the syntax for that? Sorry I am fairly novice at AS3!

Comment: Apply the event listener to every single object and then in your handler, you can get the object clicked using `event.currentTarget` (or `event.target`). target is the object that dispatched the event originally (so it could possibly be a child of your list item, you don't want that). currentTarget is the most recent object to dispatch the event (which, 99% of the time, is what you need)